# Is there an exposed API to generate Firestore IDs (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure if the method I'm currently using when I just want a Firebase auto-generated ID in my Swift app is correct. It feels a bit clunky, and I was hoping there was a better method.

These IDs are just for UUID consistency in my application and a few other use cases, so I don't want to perform a read/write operation in Firestore.

Please note, I'm not looking at any UUID generation method (e.g. `UUID().uuidString`) nor do I want to use a 3rd party lib which claims to use the same mechanism to generate UUIDs. I'm trying to specifically and explicitly generate the same IDs as Firebase, using Firebase, without incurring a read/write cost.

```swift
func generateId() -> String {
    return Firestore.firestore().collection("unused").document().documentID
}
```

Ignoring the namespacing of calling Firestore.firestore() (only doing that because of where the code is called from), this feels very strange, to create a document ref to a collection that doesn't exist (and will never exist), just to extract the document ID from the document it creates.

I would have thought/hoped there was some sort of `Firestore.generateId()` static method or utility somewhere, and maybe there is which just isn't showing up on my auto-complete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing now is your easiest option.  There is no public API for generating those random document ID strings.

If you want to make your own function, you can simply copy what Firestore does, since the client libraries are [open source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/Firestore).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I took a look at the open source code, but in the event that the Firestore IDs change (however likely/unlikely), I wanted to not have to change what I was doing.

Comment: The content of the IDs doesn't matter at all to Firestore.  The client SDK is just providing a convenient way to generate IDs that are virtually impossible to collide.  You can use whatever algorithm you want to generate IDs.

Comment: Yep, I'm using IDs in multiple ways, and for multiple purposes - using the Firebase ID is just to keep visual consistency in the documents and components that are generated. I don't want future developers to start wondering why the IDs look different and worry they have different meanings.

Comment: Amusingly, the Firebase Auth auto-generated IDs are 28 bytes... That was a bit of a surprise when I used one as a user document id. :)